# Reactive vs Non Reactive Response Time

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

For a system powerful enough to serve a number of requests (not running out of threads), would there be a difference, from the users perspective, in terms of response time / speed?

Also, would database the only thing that is usually blocking the thread, and hence we need reactive db driver?
I mean, if a rest endpoint does not make calls to db, there would be no diff whether the endpoint is reactive or not?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions and ask for opinion. Neither is allowed on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: how is this asking for opinion? im asking for a fact..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know what happens when you use project-reactor - webflux client.

Let's assume your endpoint (call it /demo) is responsible for making 5 async calls to other systems to return response from itself.

Example response times:

- Service A: 5 ms
- Service B: 50 ms
- Service C: 100 ms
- Service D: 250 ms
- Service E: 400 ms

**Typical non-weblux client way:**

5 threads are consumed, the last one is blocked for 400ms.

**Webflux client way:**

Every call to services A, B, C, D, E consume one thread, make call, returns thread and when the response comes another thread is consumed to process response.

**The final conclusion:** 
If your system will be overloaded by big amount of requests (let it be n) in the same time you will lock n threads for 400 ms.

Try to imagine the scale of the problem.

Comment: I can see that it is using less number of threads. But does it speed up user's request? From user's point of view, does it return faster on reactive case relative to non reactive? I mean, on reactive case, it still would have to take 400ms for service E to be completed and return response back to user?

Comment: If your server is not overloaded performance will be the same. It changes when you got high traffic as I mentioned above.

Comment: ooo do you mean that non reactive case, performance can go down when traffic increases ?  reactive just prevents perfoormance decline when traffic increases . i see